# Examine and tweak a given analyzer?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, analysis, stop-words

I'm using the French analyzer.

Having examined the output from [IndexClient.analyze(...)](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.11.0/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.analyze) for this analyzer I'm a little unhappy with some of the stopwords (e.g. the expression 'ayant-cause' comes out as 'caus', because 'ayant' is a stopword: [French stopwords](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/analysis/common/src/resources/org/apache/lucene/analysis/snowball/french_stop.txt)).

How do I go about examining these stopwords and then tweaking them? Do I have to create a custom analyzer based on the existing French one? Or can I directly tweak the French one?

NB I am using the Python [`elasticsearch`](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.11.0/index.html) module ("thin client"), but an answer in terms of REST commands would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily tweak the existing analyzer and examine them using the [Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) of elasticsearch

Ultimately analyzer is made of three things, char filter, tokeniser and token-filter and you can create your own combination of these things to build your own custom analyzer and test it using the REST API.

Comment: Thanks. I know this and where the API docs are. The question was "how". Any chance you might give a simple code example (NOT of analysing a phrase, which I know how to do, but of listing the characteristics of an analyser)? I can't even see how one might list the stop words of an analyser. The API docs don't explain enough.

Comment: @mikerodent makes sense, I have also not come across where ES returns the list of stop words of an analyzer using the REST API, and like the way you searched and found github page which list, I used to find that but let me try to find more info

Answer (score 0):

Spent quite a bit of time figuring out at least a workaround arrangement.

Having downloaded that French stop-words file from Github I then edited it (e.g. to exclude "ayant"). Currently residing in the "config" directory of my installed ES setup (although you can set an absolute path).

Then I made my settings/mappings object like this:

```
{
    'settings' : {
        'analysis' : {
            'analyzer' : {
                'tweaked_french' : {
                    'type' : 'french',
                    # NB W10, config path currently D:\apps\ElasticSearch\elasticsearch-7.10.2\config
                    'stopwords_path' : 'tweaked_french_stop.txt',
                },
            },
        },
    },
    
    'mappings': {
        'dynamic': 'strict',
        'properties': {
            'my_french_field' : {
                'type' : 'text',
                'term_vector' : 'with_positions_offsets',
                'fields' : {
                    'french' : {
                        'type' : 'text',
                        'analyzer' : 'tweaked_french',
                        'term_vector' : 'with_positions_offsets',
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
```

What is then rather wonderful is that, according to my experiments, you can get a query object to find and use that custom-built analyser (i.e. it's there and available, in the installed index). So your query object is relatively simple:

```
{
    'query': {
        'simple_query_string': {
            'query': query_text,
            'fields': [
                'my_french_field.french',
            ],
            'analyzer' : 'tweaked_french',
        },
    },
    'highlight': {
        'fields': {
            'my_french_field.french': {
                'type': 'fvh',

                ...

            },
        },
        'number_of_fragments': 0
    }
}
```

After that you can query in French: your query gets stemmed and the result is used for the search. If "ayant" is a word in your query string, it will now return hits including "ayant-cause", proving that both the query and the mapping spec are using the tweaked stop-word list.

I'd still like to know whether a way exists not involving using an external file, i.e. of editing on-the-fly what is already there (or of just *seeing* what it already there...).